# Any Good JavaScript Animation Framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, frameworks

Since the last time someone asked this a lot of water ran through the internet. We have canvas, VML and other fancy stuff.

What are currently the based animation and graphics frameworks for javascript?

Comment: "a lot of water ran through the internet" - really? I hope it didn't short-circuit any of the routers.

Comment: It really depends on what you need to do. Animation can be very different. I've seen a lot of good animation plugin for jQuery. For canvas I used Raphael, it's crossbrowser and pretty fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have u ever saw this kind of animation! I am working on a site lately which I am using this kind of animation/movements a lot! they sounds really cool for me, check it out:

http://webdev.stephband.info/parallax.html

Comment: An interesting link but it seems to be specifically for that kind of view. Not a general animation framework which the OP was asking for.

Comment: Sorry, i thought u were asking some good idea for animation!